# Clipping multiple cclayers inside of a parent cclayer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCScrollLayer` that i would like to set up multiple `CCLayer`s inside of it to swipe pages back and fourth. Some of the content expands over the page `CCLayer` and into the next page, so while swiping you can see things from the previous page pushing onto the next one. What i would like to achieve is similar to the `UIView` function where it clips to the bounds, where you will not see anything outside the contentSize of the layer. Does anyone know how to go about doing this? I would like the size of the page to being the size of the devices screen. I've tried doing this but it doesn't give the desired result:

```
kmGLPushMatrix();
  glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
  CGPoint startingPoint = ccp(0,0);
  glScissor(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
  glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
kmGLPopMatrix();
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at a CCClippingNode (cocos2d version 2.+) ... Visit at the visit method to get some inspiration. Here, from the doc:

```
/** CCClippingNode is a subclass of CCNode.
 It draws its content (childs) clipped using a stencil.
 The stencil is an other CCNode that will not be drawn.
 The clipping is done using the alpha part of the stencil (adjusted with an alphaThreshold).
*/
```